# Create Custom Search Bar

Tags: java, android

I would like to add a search bar to my activity that should look like this:

[image]

My Layout.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar" android:id="@+id/header"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
<EditText android:id="@+id/ean" android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1.5"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/search" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/Search"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
style="@android:style/ButtonBar" android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<Button android:id="@+id/cancel" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/cancel"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />
<Button android:id="@+id/light" android:layout_width="0.0dip"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/light"
android:layout_weight="1.0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Graphical Layout looks like this:
[image]

How can i style my layout that it looks like in the image above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try and replace the `Button` by an `ImageButton`. Then I'd create 9patch images for both the button and the text box and assign them using a style.

Answer (score 0):

is just nothing. just design your theme in xml layout file with that particulate background
and add one editText and button as per your design and access that by activity.

comment me if need further help.

thanks

Comment: i add code in the Thorsten Dittmar ans by misteck you can seen there.